# Expose method in Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I'm a new Thymeleaf user, so, I'm sorry if this is a too basic question, but I've tried searching it and couldn't find any results.

I've been working to integrate Thymeleaf in a brazilian web portal product and I want to be able to do something like `<div th:text="${myfunc('some val')}"></div>` (calling a custom method from Thymeleaf).

I know that I can do `<div th:text="${myobj.myfunc('some val')}"></div>`, but I don't want to expose the method `myfunc` inside an object.

In the integration, I've already created a custom `IContext` to expose some custom variables (this is working perfectly).

How could I do that?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do that by implementing an `IEngineContextFactory` that returns an implementation of `IEngineContext` that contains the method I want to expose.